# Is it okay to decline a work-trip to a seminar that is on booked-holiday time?

Tags: professionalism, travel, time-off

I have booked holiday from a month in advance and I've just been asked to attend a seminar on email marketing for my company on one of the days that is booked.

My boss has asked if I could move one of my holiday days and attend the workshop. The next workshop is the same date the following month.

Comment: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695

Comment: He asked if you could. Can you reasonably do so (where "reasonably" includes committments to others AND to yourself)? If the answer is no, say no.

Comment: as a "What should I do?" question, this is likely to be closed. Any answer would depend strongly on your company culture and norms. You could edit it to ask how to know whether pushing back on your boss' request, or how to word your pushback. That might be a more answerable question.

Comment: Your question is incomplete: *can* you move one of your holiday days? What would be required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the boss you already booked the trip. What you tell you boss after you just told him that you booked the trip depends upon your circumstance:

1. The trip is a one-time, no backout option deal - it's a wedding, an engagement, Uncle Elmer wanting to see you one last time because he's not going to see his next birthday, a family reunion for which you will NOT be forgiven if you don't show up. The familia and the amigos know where you live and they know how to hit you where it hurts :)
2. You can get exactly what happened at the marketing workshop from the training materials that are brought back and by discussing with co-workers and whoever else is attending.
3. The trip is not a one time no backout option deal. You have enough time to reschedule it without paying rescheduling fees.
4. The trip is not a one time no backout option deal but you will be paying rescheduling fees and they amount to X dollars, euros, etc.

The subsequent flow of the conversation follows from how your boss reacts to what you say.

Answer (score 1):

It is just common sense, really.

You check how important it is for you and your boss that you go to the seminar. You check how important it is for you to have the holiday. Then you check whether your boss is the type who appreciates it if you give up a day of holiday, or whether he is the type who takes you for a mug who can be taken advantage of.

You add all these together, and depending on the result you give up your holiday or not. It is of course absolutely professional to say "no" if that summation told you that you shouldn't give up the holiday. You deserve a holiday, you booked it, so you should get it on the day it was booked. Of course blindly insisting on getting a holiday without considering the situation would be unprofessional.

There might be extreme cases, like the holiday is your honeymoon with your freshly married husband or wife, and total disaster has struck your company and they really really REALLY need you - in that case you would want an awful lot of appreciation. But the principle is the same.